# Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive

Tags: google-chrome, phpmyadmin, content-security-policy

I noticed after updating to Google Chrome (21.0.1180.89) I’m getting allot of errors in the developer tab; especially if I visit my own phpMyAdmin site.

There are all the same and are some sort of security against Cross-Site Scripting; are there anything I can do to resolve?

```
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'allow'. 
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'options'.
```

Comment: I have this problem too: I'm on Chrome "21.0.1180.89 m" on Windows XP.  It causes the javascript on the page to stop executing which means the some of the UI is not functional.

Answer (score 2):

The `allow` and `options` directives are both part of Mozilla's original definition of Content Security Policy. Chrome implements the [current W3C standard](http://w3.org/TR/CSP), which has made several changes from Mozilla's original proposal.

- `allow` has been replaced with `default-src`, and sets a default source list for the other CSP directives.
- `options` has been replaced with `'unsafe-inline'` and `'unsafe-eval'` (with the single-quotes) sources on either the `script-src` or `style-src` directives.

Both of those old-style directive still work in Firefox, using the `X-Content-Security-Policy` header. If a website delivers a WebKit-prefixed header (`X-WebKit-CSP`), it should use the current standard.

Note that WebKit has implemented the unprefixed header (`Content-Security-Policy`) in trunk, and it should be rolling out to stable WebKit-based browsers over the next few months. If you're not already setting the canonical header, now is a good time to start thinking about it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Got a similar error on Chrome v 48.0.2564.116 m
"Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'frame-ancestors'."
But working absolutely fine on IE 11, FF and safari.

This is just an warning message on chrome and there is no impact on the functionality of the site.